# PHP cURL Dynamic Address

Tags: php, curl

In my organization, I can access all the printer details by typing the IP of that printer in the Browser's URL. The Logs page of the printer has a dynamic URL(with a 'dummy' variable changing at each instant..their source code involves usage of the Date and getTime functions). Well this is the code i wrote for generating the dynamic http address of the logs page.

```
 <html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getu() {
    var now_time = new Date();
 var cgi_str = "http://10.128.57.200/jlp.cgi?Flag=Html_Data&LogType=0&Dummy=" + now_time.getTime();
      document.getElementById("address").value=cgi_str ;
    } 
</script>
  </head>

<body onLoad="getu()">

<form id="mldsform" action="curlexp2.php"  method="post" >
<input type="hidden" id="address" name="address" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" />

</form>

  </body>   
  </html>
```

And the curlexp2.php has the code:

```
<?php
$proxy = "10.128.60.40:3128";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$_POST["address"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "$proxy");

$result= curl_exec ($ch);
echo $result;
curl_close ($ch);  
?>
```

This is what i get on execution:

```
User information is disabled.
This operation cannot be accepted. User certification is invalid or date expired.
Update page.
                                                         OK
```

However when i just echo out $_POST["address"],  i am able to get the correct address. Any clues anyone??
Thanks in advance for your help..

Comment: What is displayed if you open your URL (10.128.57.200) in the browser?

Comment: @Roman Newaza - I am able to get the printer details, which involves all the product specifications,status of printer, last updated..

Comment: What does alert(cgi_str); show? Or just replace hidden with text to see the value...

Comment: when i echo out cgi_str, am able to get the HTTP Address of the page i want which has all the logs.