# cURL php dynamic http address load

Tags: php, curl

I am using cURL to get contents of a web page whose http address is dynamic.I am able to detect the dynamic address at each time instant.  However, when i execute it, i get the message

```
User information is disabled.
This operation cannot be accepted. User certification is invalid or date expired.
Update page.
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: can this be of some help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519939/make-curl-follow-redirects

Comment: looks like this is security certificate related issue. What URL are you trying to call. What happens when you try to load a URL in say Chrome browser. did you try making a call on plain http. Also it could be redirection problem. if you can provide more code that would be helpful

Comment: what info dose curl_getinfo() gets you, is it a http_code = 200?

Comment: @PugganSe curl_getinfo() RETURNS 0 .

Comment: @JaspreetChahal Full details are given in
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256392/php-curl-dynamic-address
Also the URL I am trying to call has all the log details of printer. And when i load URL in browser, I am still getting the same error thing as above.

But hey note that if i type IP of printer in browser to ee the details, and then again type the dynamic URL generated by my code, it works.  But still, while using curl, the error shows up!!

Comment: @saur 0 = FALSE, its failed, the first parameter should by a open curl resource, and its should be run between exec and close